What are the rules for punctuation marks in Ancient Greek texts?
I have a lot of different versions of the Greek New Testament, and they all seem to follow more or less unique rules when it comes to their use of punctuation marks. For example, the Byzantine NT always writes a capital letter after dots and Greek question marks; this is not the case in the NA28 or Scrivener NT. The Byzantine NT and Scrivener NT also very often place a comma before "και" and kind of mimic the way it is used in modern English. The Scrivener NT also uses parantheses, while the rest of the texts instead use commas.
Are there any standard rules for which punctuation marks should be used in ancient Greek texts and how?

It would be fair to say the rules of punctuation for such a text depend upon how close the editor prefers it to be to the modern system. As Parkes remarks in the introduction of his Pause and Effect: An Introduction to the History of Punctuation in the West,

Punctuation is a phenomenon of written language, and its history is
bound up with that of the written medium. In Antiquity the written
word was regarded as a record of the spoken word, and texts were
usually read aloud. But from the sixth century onwards attitudes to
the written word changed: writing came to be regarded as conveying
information directly to the mind through the eye, and Isidore of
Seville (c. 560-636) could state a preference for silent reading
which subsequently became established as the norm. The written medium
developed as a separate manifestation of language with a status
equivalent to, but independent of that of any spoken counterpart.

Hence, roughly, the development and practice of punctuation have shifted the focus through the history from a rhetorical outlook that prioritises eloquence to the one that regards punctuation as a constituent of syntax.
Specifically for the history of Greek punctuation, a comprehensive account is succinctly presented by Nick Nicholas on his website. The following is his own summary of it at Quora, which, I hope, helps to have a clear sight of the situation:


The basics of punctuation as we know it in both Latin in Greek were in place by around the 10th century, including commas, periods, and
interrogatives. They appear to have developed independently, although
they had common antecedents in Roman era punctuation, as pioneered in
Alexandria.
The high dot was Alexandrian, and ended up with the function of the semicolon in Latin.
The Greek question mark developed at the same time as the Latin interrogative, but it looked like the Latin semicolon, and has not
changed.
The high dot also performed the function of the Latin colon. Typesetting of Ancient Greek still often uses the high dot in that
function. Modern Greek now uses the colon instead.
The other shared punctuation—exclamation mark, parentheses, dashes, ellipses, quotation marks—are Renaissance innovations, introduced into
Greek from Latin script.
Different countries punctuate Ancient Greek following their local norms—e.g. use of quotation marks, propensity to ellipses and
exclamation marks, etc. The Modern Greek preferences in punctuation
are French: use of guillemets, use of quotation dashes, etc. Greek
also used expanded typing (Sperrdruck) from German instead of italics,
although that is now out of fashion.


